# Directly Jump to another C++ function

Tags: c++, assembly, systems-programming

I'm porting a small academic OS from TriCore to ARM Cortex (Thumb-2 instruction set). For the scheduler to work, I sometimes need to JUMP directly to another function without modifying the stack nor the link register.

On TriCore (or, rather, on tricore-g++), this wrapper template (for any three-argument-function) works:

```
template< class A1, class A2, class A3 > 
inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) 
JUMP3( void (*func)( A1, A2, A3), A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3 ) {
    typedef void (* __attribute__((interrupt_handler)) Jump3)( A1, A2, A3);
    ( (Jump3)func )( a1, a2, a3 );
}

//example for using the template:
JUMP3( superDispatch, this, me, next );
```

This would generate the assembler instruction `J` (a.k.a. JUMP) instead of `CALL`, leaving the stack and CSAs unchanged when jumping to the (otherwise normal) C++ function `superDispatch(SchedulerImplementation* obj, Task::Id from, Task::Id to)`.

Now I need an equivalent behaviour on ARM Cortex (or, rather, for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++), i.e. generate a `B` (a.k.a. BRANCH) instruction instead of `BLX` (a.k.a. BRANCH with link and exchange). But there is no `interrupt_handler` attribute for arm-g++ and I could not find any equivalent attribute.

So I tried to resort to `asm volatile` and writing the asm code directly:

```
template< class A1, class A2, class A3 > 
inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) 
JUMP3( void (*func)( A1, A2, A3), A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3 ) {
    asm volatile (
                  "mov.w r0, %1;"
                  "mov.w r1, %2;"
                  "mov.w r2, %3;"
                  "b %0;"
                            :
                            : "r"(func), "r"(a1), "r"(a2), "r"(a3)
                            : "r0", "r1", "r2"
                  );
}
```

So far, so good, in my theory, at least. Thumb-2 requires function arguments to be passed in the registers, i.e. r0..r2 in this case, so it should work.

But then the linker dies with

```
undefined reference to `r6'
```

on the closing bracket of the asm statement ... and I don't know what to make of it. OK, I'm not the expert in C++, and the asm syntax is not very straightforward... so has anybody got a hint for me? A hint to the correct `__attribute__` for arm-g++ would be one way, a hint to fix the asm code would be another. Another way maybe would be to tell the compiler that `a1..a3` should already be in the registers `r0..r2` when the asm statement is entered (I looked into that a bit, but did not find any hint).

Comment: Are a1, a2, a3 a pointers? try to convert them to `(void*)`

Comment: The attribute for an ARM interrupt handler is `interrupt`. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: @Mike: nope, that attribute still generates a `BLX` instruction...

Comment: @osgx: they are not neccessarily pointers ...

Comment: And you can declare variables to be in specific registers like this: `register int reg0 asm("r0") = a1;`. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: The link error's a bit odd. Could you show the code that calls `JUMP3`, and the declaration of the function it's passing as `func`?

Comment: @Mike: (1) I'll try that; (2) Either I don't understand what you mean -- or you overlooked it in the question text...

Comment: I was thinking that the error might be due to the way the template was instantiated. But it isn't - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I now figured out what went wrong.

The whole concept of JUMPing directly to another function is moot on ARM Cortex, because TriCore uses a Context Save Area (CSA) to save the whole CPU context everytime you call another function. Think of it as a second, independent stack that grows with each `CALL` and shrinks with each `RET`. And each CSA block has constant size.

ARM Cortex, on the other hand, uses a simple standard stack (ok, it knows about a system stack and a thread stack, but that's unimportant here) -- and GCC just saves what it needs for each function, so each frame has a different size. Simply jumping to another function therefore is out of the question, because the stack will be corrupt as soon as the jumped-to function starts saving the non-volatile registers it uses.

And about the linker error with the undefined reference to r6 ... well, I should have read the instruction set documentation more carefully. `B` is an unconditional branch to an *immediate* address, `BX` is the instruction that expects the branch address in a register. I was fooled by the instruction list in the manual where `BX` was shortly described as "Branch with exchange". I did not want to exchange anything, I wanted a simple jump, so I did not read further.

So, after exchanging `B` with `BX` in the `asm volatile` code, the code compiled. But, as pointed out above, the whole concept cannot work as expected. Maybe someone else can find a use case for that code, I have to resort to classic function calling now ...

Answer (score 1):

The link error is caused by trying to use the branch instruction to jump to a pointer. This generates code like `b r6`, which fails to link because `r6` isn't a symbol. Change the branch instruction to `mov pc,%0`, and you should get the correct jump.

As I mentioned in the comments, ARM interrupt handlers are declared with an `interrupt` attribute, but as you found this doesn't effect how they're called. I guess that was a platform-specific trick that happened to do the right thing on TriCore.

You could try declaring variables in specific registers using GCC's extended syntax, `register int reg0 asm("r0") = a1;` rather than volatile `mov` instructions. This might allow the compiler to generate better code.